# How to bind table id to DOM in ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my project, I want to do something when checkbox is clicked.

Here is my code which works OK:

```
<script>
window.onload=function() 
{
  var uTId = document.getElementById('uTId');       
  uTId.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
   if(ev.target.getAttribute("type") == "checkbox"){
   alert("xietest");
   }
 },false);
}
</script>

<div  class="easyui-panel" id="pp"  >
  <table class="uTb" id="uTId" cellspacing="0" style="100%" >
    <tr>
        <td ><input type="checkbox" id="Jack"/>Jack</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And "xietest" can be appeared in page successfully when checkbox is clicked;

But actually the content of pp easyui-panel is from ajax , like:

```
<script>
...
  $.ajax({
 .......
 success:function(data){
   var drfV='<table class="uTb" id="uTId" cellspacing="0" style="100%" >';
     drfV=drfV+'<tr><td ><input type="checkbox" value="'+data.name+'"/>'+data.name+'</td>';
     drfV=drfV+'</tr></table>';
     $('#pp').html("");
     $('#pp').append(drfV);
   }
  });
....
window.onload=function() 
{
  var uTId = document.getElementById('uTId');       
  uTId.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
   if(ev.target.getAttribute("type") == "checkbox"){
   alert("xietest");
   }
 },false);
}
</script>

<div  class="easyui-panel" id="pp"></div>
```

Now It works fail, "xietest" can not show like before.

I know that table id uTId should not be found in DOM as it was loaded after window onload.

But I don't know how to bind table id uTId to DOM, Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you can't declare an event for unloaded dom element yet. You should handle all success events and define the event after. So, you could use `setInterval` to apply it.

```
var ajax1Success = true;
var ajax2Success = true;
success: function(data) {
     var drfV = '<table class="uTb" id="uTId" cellspacing="0" style="100%" >';
     drfV = drfV + '<tr><td ><input type="checkbox" value="' + data.name + '"/>' + data.name + '</td>';
     drfV = drfV + '</tr></table>';
     $('#pp').html("");
     $('#pp').append(drfV);
     //Declare the event
     ajax1Success = true;
}
success: function(data) {
     var drfV = '<table class="uTb" id="uTId" cellspacing="0" style="100%" >';
     drfV = drfV + '<tr><td ><input type="checkbox" value="' + data.name + '"/>' + data.name + '</td>';
     drfV = drfV + '</tr></table>';
     $('#pp').html("");
     $('#pp').append(drfV);
     //Declare the event
     ajax2Success = true;
}
var t = window.setInterval(function () {
    var ajaxSuccess = ajax1Success || ajax2Success;
    if (ajaxSuccess == true) {
        clearInterval(t);//Clear the interval after at least one ajax call have been succeeded
        var uTId = document.getElementById('uTId');
        uTId.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
            if (ev.target.getAttribute("type") == "checkbox") {
                alert("xietest");
            }
        });
    }

}, 1000);
```

Comment: The td content of pp  uTId table  is changing which is from ten different ajax success function. I want the even code is  independent, rather than each function has it